# How to Identify duplicate value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a table `employee_monitor` below

| Name | Code | ValueGain |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Zakir | 10 | 15 |
| Zakir | 10 | 16 |
| Tame | 11 | 19 |
| Raya | 12 | 12 |
| Zakir | 10 | 20 |
| Tame | 11 | 28 |

Now need a query for the below result

| Name | Code | ValueGain | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Zakir | 10 | 15 | 1 |
| Zakir | 10 | 16 | 0 |
| Tame | 11 | 19 | 1 |
| Raya | 12 | 12 | 1 |
| Zakir | 10 | 20 | 0 |
| Tame | 11 | 28 | 0 |

`Rank` value `0` mean duplicate `code`.

Comment: Does the assignation of rank = 1 for code 10 (for example) have any logic or don't you care as long as there is only one 1?

Comment: @P.Salmon, code 10 = 1 , not at all; 1 for once employee. 0 for duplicate employees.

Answer (score 2):

If you determine a duplicate by the order of the `ValueGain` column, I think the answer is the following statement.

```sql
SELECT Name, Code, ValueGain, (
    SELECT 1 - Count(*)
    FROM TableName as T2
    WHERE T1.Name = T2.Name AND T1.Code = T2.Code AND T1.ValueGain > T2.ValueGain
    LIMIT 1
) as Rank FROM TableName as T1;
```

The inner query searches for equal `Name` and `Code` with higher `ValueGain`, returns at most 1 result and counts that. As you want to have it the other way round, invert it by subtraction.

Comment: Rank becomes a reserved word from version 8.